# Check for the presence of a sub-list

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

Can you provide me a performing (possibly idiomatic) way to check if a list `A` is a sublist of a given list `B`?

E.g.

```
isSubList(List(1,2), List(1,2,3,4)) // => true
isSubList(List(1,2), List(5,6,7,8)) // => false
```

Comment: It's unclear whether you want a subset or a slice. For instance, is `List(1,3)` a sublist of `List(1,2,3)` (it would be a sublist of `List(1,3,5)`, clearly)?

Comment: Duplicate question see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650325/1586965

Answer (score 26, accepted):

One way would be to use `forall` and `contains`:

```
scala>   List(1, 2).forall(List(1, 2, 3, 4).contains)
res3: Boolean = true

scala>   List(1, 2).forall(List(5, 6, 7, 8).contains)
res4: Boolean = false

scala>   List(1, 2).forall(List(5, 6, 2, 9).contains)
res5: Boolean = false
```

Note that this approach doesn't consider ordering:

```
scala>   List(1, 2).forall(List(2, 1).contains)
res6: Boolean = true
```

Probably you could use also `Set`s and `intersect`, but I think this way is preferable.

Comment: In practice one shouldn't put something like `List(1, 2, 3, 4)`  inside a lambda as it will create the list over and over.

Comment: If order is important: `def isSubList[A] (short:Seq[A], long:Seq[A]): Boolean = long.containsSlice(short)`. Credit goes to below poster, upvote their post if this helped!

Answer (score 22):

If order matters you can use containsSlice, which check whether collections contains a given sequence as a slice

```
def isSubList[A](l1:List[A], l2:List[A]) = l2.containsSlice(l1)
```

Comment: More readable: `def isSubList[A] (short:Seq[A], long:Seq[A]): Boolean = long.containsSlice(short)`

Answer (score 2):

One more solution:

```
def isSubList[A](short: List[A], long: List[A]): Boolean =
    long.tails exists (_.startsWith(short))
```

However, it would be much more efficient if lists were converted to streams first:

```
def isSubList[A](short: List[A], long: List[A]): Boolean = {
    val sLong = long.toStream
    val sShort = short.toStream
    sLong.tails exists (_.startsWith(sShort))
}
```

This way, not all tails have to be generated. Also startsWith is evaluated in a short circuit fashion